# How to get items out of a list and create a new one in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i have the below task, my goal is to get values larger than 5 into a new list(new_list):

```
- name: Run with items greater than 5
  ansible.builtin.command: echo {{ item }}
  loop: [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
  when: item > 5
  register: new_list

- debug:
    var: new_list
```

however i get the below output,

actual output here https://anotepad.com/notes/iqrpfkxk (output too large for post)

i would expect to get [ 6, 8, 10 ], basically how to i get rid of all that extra output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_fact` to store the values greater than 5 into a new array (`new_list`). For that the task can be executed conditionally.

Example:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      new_list: "{{ new_list|default([]) + [item] }}"
    when: item > 5
    loop: [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
  - debug:
      var: new_list
```

Produces:

```
    "new_list": [
        6,
        8,
        10
    ]
```

*Update:*

Although not required for the above example. There is some documentation on how to limit loop output [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label).

Answer (score 0):

[Select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#select) the items. For example

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: item
    loop: "{{ [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]|select('gt', 5)|list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item: 6
  item: 8
  item: 10
```